# Update django model database with ForeignKey by using serializer

Tags: python-3.x, django, django-models, django-rest-framework

I have created a django `model` which includes a foreign key to a user as follows:

```
from authentication.models import User
from django.db import models

class Event(models.Model):
    
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)
    dr_notice_period = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
    dr_duration = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
    dr_request = models.FloatField(blank=True, null=True)
```

My `serializers.py` file is as follows:

```
class EventSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    user = UserSerializer(many=True, read_only=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Event
        fields = ['user', 'dr_notice_period', 'dr_duration', 'dr_request']
```

What I need to do is to go to a url and with a POST request to upload the data to the database, but without specifically specifying the user.

My `views.py` is as follows:

```
from rest_framework.response import Response
from rest_framework.decorators import api_view
from rest_framework import status

from vpp_optimization.serializers import EventSerializer

@api_view(['POST'])
def event(request):

    serializer = EventSerializer(data=request.data)

    if serializer.is_valid():
        instance = serializer.save(commit=False)
        instance.user = request.user
        instance.save()
        return Response({"status": "success", "data": serializer.data}, status=status.HTTP_200_OK)
    else:
        return Response({"status": "error", "data": serializer.errors}, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

As I study I thought that by using `commit=False` in `save` would solve the problem, but I am getting the following error:

```
'commit' is not a valid keyword argument to the 'save()' method. If you need to access data before committing to the database then inspect 'serializer.validated_data' instead. You can also pass additional keyword arguments to 'save()' if you need to set extra attributes on the saved model instance. For example: 'serializer.save(owner=request.user)'.'
```

Is there a better way to do what I intent to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You pass the user as parameter, so:

```
if serializer.is_valid():
    instance = serializer.save(user=request.user)
        return Response({'status': 'success', 'data': serializer.data}, status=status.HTTP_200_OK)
```

---

> **Note**: It is normally better to make use of the [**`settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL`** <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/#std:setting-AUTH_USER_MODEL) to refer to the user model, than to use the [**`User`** model <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/auth/#django.contrib.auth.models.User) directly. For more information you can see the [*referencing the `User` model* section of the documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/customizing/#referencing-the-user-model).

Comment: I changed to what you propose and I got the following error: Cannot assign "<django.contrib.auth.models.AnonymousUser object at 0x7f7daf1469d0>": "Event.user" must be a "User" instance.

Comment: @Kosmylo: that is because you are not logged in when you make the POST request, so `request.user` is the `AnonymousUser`.